# AWS vpc creation using ansible on Mac OS X

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I have a problem while creating aws vpc from mac os x but the exact same command/role is working from ubuntu.

Steps that I have already taken on Mac OS X:

- update the time using ntp
- upgrade the ansible to version 2
- downgrade the ansible to version 1.9.1,1.9.2,1.9.3 and 1.9.4
- boto version is 2.38.0

With all above changes, I am getting this error:

```
PLAY ***************************************************************************

TASK [vpc : Creating an AWS VPC inside mentioned Region] ***********************
task path: /Users/arbab/ansible2/aws/roles/vpc/tasks/main.yml:2
ESTABLISH LOCAL CONNECTION FOR USER: xxxxxxxxx
127.0.0.1 EXEC ( umask 22 && mkdir -p "$( echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1453191395.76-205801730631196 )" && echo "$( echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1453191395.76-205801730631196 )" )
127.0.0.1 PUT /var/folders/rq/yhlwx3c971x6p88qwmvhpg600000gn/T/tmpoyL88U TO /Users/arbab/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1453191395.76-205801730631196/ec2_vpc
127.0.0.1 EXEC LANG=en_US.UTF-8 LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8 /usr/bin/python /Users/arbab/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1453191395.76-205801730631196/ec2_vpc; rm -rf "/Users/arbab/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1453191395.76-205801730631196/" > /dev/null 2>&1
An exception occurred during task execution. The full traceback is:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/arbab/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1453191395.76-205801730631196/ec2_vpc", line 2867, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/arbab/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1453191395.76-205801730631196/ec2_vpc", line 700, in main
    (vpc_dict, new_vpc_id, subnets_changed, igw_id, changed) = create_vpc(module, vpc_conn)
  File "/Users/arbab/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1453191395.76-205801730631196/ec2_vpc", line 338, in create_vpc
    previous_vpc = find_vpc(module, vpc_conn, id, cidr_block)
  File "/Users/arbab/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1453191395.76-205801730631196/ec2_vpc", line 198, in find_vpc
    previous_vpcs = vpc_conn.get_all_vpcs(None, {'cidr': cidr, 'state': 'available'})
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/boto/vpc/__init__.py", line 111, in get_all_vpcs
    return self.get_list('DescribeVpcs', params, [('item', VPC)])
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/boto/connection.py", line 1186, in get_list
    raise self.ResponseError(response.status, response.reason, body)
boto.exception.EC2ResponseError: EC2ResponseError: 401 Unauthorized
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response><Errors><Error><Code>AuthFailure</Code><Message>AWS was not able to validate the provided access credentials</Message></Error></Errors><RequestID>2318e170-a400-499c-8713-4c0b3ec1850d</RequestID></Response>

fatal: [127.0.0.1]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "invocation": {"module_name": "ec2_vpc"}, "parsed": false}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
127.0.0.1                  : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1
```

Comment: Could you include the task or reference the role (in github or galaxy)?

Comment: This one? https://github.com/arbabnazar/ansible-aws-vpc-ha-wordpress

Comment: @Michael the above mentioned link is my repo. This works on Linux but not Mac OS X

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error there is an unauthorized error

```
boto.exception.EC2ResponseError: EC2ResponseError: 401 Unauthorized
```

Could you check via `env` command if the AWS credentials are setup properly? The names that ansible expect are:

```
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID='AK123'
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY='abc123'
```

Comment: Thanks @Javier Segura, it was old un-used credentials there... env is a tip